# Migrating to the new Stripe Payment method using the payment element from card element

Tags: stripe-payments

Im currently migrating over from the sources API to the newer payment method API.
With the old sources API, my checkout page only collected card information and placed a hold on the amount to be charged in the future (when application is approved at a later time). If the card declined for any reason we used to be able to notify the user right away as the hold would fail even before capturing at the later time of approval.

I want this same behaviour to migrate over to the new API, but the issue is when using the test cards that flag a payment failure, I only get the failure after trying to confirm the payment intent (`paymentIntent.Confirm`) at approval, which comes after setting up a payment_method in our front end using `stripe.createPaymentMethod`. which returns a `paymentMethod` but no errors.

I need to know while the user is on the checkout page of the card failure to give them the chance to re-enter their card information again or till we know it will succeed at when confirming the payment.

I am able to get a an error when attaching the `paymentMethod` to a customer. but were not always saving the card as it is an option given to the user.

Thank you

The current flow is.

Client Side:

create payment method

Server Side:

create Payment intent

optional: attach payment method to customer

confirm payment intent

Answer (score 0):

Surfacing the error will depend a lot on what product(s) you're using on the front-end. For example: if you're using the [Payment Element](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-element), then you would get a decline message in-line with the form:

[Payment Element card decline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCnYc.png)

But if you're using the [Card Element](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/card-element), then you would need to retrieve the error from the API response that Stripe sends back and surface that yourself via a custom UI. The `paymentIntent.confirm` method *does return an error*, but it returns it to the client, so you would need to listen for the response on the front-end and surface the error there.

Comment: Yes exactly im moving from card-element to the payment-element. The paymentIntent.confirm is happening in the server side at a later time.